# Sorted ArrayList Not Appearing as Sorted when I run app

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, collections

I have an `ArrayList` that I have sorted using `compareTo`. When I run the program, I get a list in the order that I inputted items into the list, even though I know I have sorted it.

I call `Collections.sort()` on the `ArrayList` but nothing happens. When I do `Collections.reverse()` the list appears in backwards order of how I had originally entered it.

```
public int compareTo(LeaderPlayers players)
    {
        int compareTo=((LeaderPlayers)players).getScore();
        return this.score-compareTo;
    }
```

This is how I compare and use `Collections.sort()` to sort the list.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ArrayList<String> workshopParticipants = new ArrayList<String>();
        workshopParticipants.add("Christine");
        workshopParticipants.add("Marty");
        workshopParticipants.add("Tom");
        workshopParticipants.add("JeanMarie");
        workshopParticipants.add("Daniel");

        Collections.sort(workshopParticipants);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, workshopParticipants);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the `RecyclerView`, the participants appear in the order Christine, Marty, Tom, JeanMarie, Daniel.

I want them to appear in the order of number of points they have, which I have not shown here. I have clearly sorted it, but it does not show as sorted. Could it be because of the `RecyclerView` I have used?

Comment: WorkshopParticipants is a List of String your compare function does not factor into the sorting here 

PS why are you casting players to LEaderPlayer ?

Comment: you probably want to do something like workshopParticipans stream().map(str->new LeaderPLayers(str)).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())

even though I dont know where you get the scores from in this case

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting `String` names of the players. You need to sort `LeaderPlayers` objects that have the `score` value, not just their names. Assuming you have a class:

```java
class LeaderPlayers implements Comparable<LeaderPlayers> {
  String name;
  int score;
  ...
}
```

You need to do:

```java
List<LeaderPlayers> players = new ArrayList<>();
players.add(new LeaderPlayers("Christine", 30));
players.add(new LeaderPlayers("Marta", 20))
players.add(new LeaderPlayers("Alice", 10));
Collections.sort(players);
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Java-8 you can do like below:**

```
    ArrayList<String> FinalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    FinalList= workshopParticipants.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    System.out.println(FinalList);
```